# popBack to selected tab's first view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am working on an application having 5 tabs. on tab 3 i have nav_controller>> tableVC>> detailVC. When i click on push notification, it opens up to detailVC. The problem is that, after going back, I want the tableVC to be opened up, but it is popping the recently opened VC. I don't want that.

Even if i am working on any other tab, after clicking on notification and going back,  i want tab 3 to be selected and tableVC to be opened up.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
UINavigationController *navVc=(UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;
                                             [navVc pushViewController:objVC animated:YES];
```

this is the way I open DetailVC from appDel.m

Any other method for this flow is welcomed.

Comment: How do you open from push? You need to show us your code if you want to get some help.

Comment: @ozgur check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to jump to a view controller in the navigation stack.
Just import the viewController to jump as:

```
#import "SettingsViewController.h"
```

The code is as follows:-

```
    //for (UIViewController* viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
    //{
        //if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[SettingsViewController class]] )
        //{
            SettingsViewController *listController = (SettingsViewController*)viewController;
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:listController animated:YES];
        //}
    //}
```

Hopr this helps.

Comment: but that viewController is not always in my navigation stack.

Comment: try it out first. I am using it for a similar app flow.

Comment: Is it working when you open the detailsVC going through the tableVC.

Comment: No. at that time also, I m not getting ListVC in stack. as i am opening app from background.

Comment: in the normal case its working like navigating when it is in stack.

Comment: SettingsViewController *listController = (SettingsViewController*)viewController;
                [self.navigationController popToViewController:listController animated:YES];

Comment: The above solution in comment should work for all cases. Sorry my bad.

Comment: testing in device. that why not getting any error message.

Comment: if you run on device through xcode without disconnecting then also you get logs.

Comment: im doing that way only. but not getting any log.

Comment: if u have any other method for this flow. then tell me.